# How to remember focused element on lazyRow when it is not focused? Jetpack compose android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I would like to make lazyColumn with lazy rows which will be scrolled separately. Also one element would have focus with scrolling. but when I would change focus on other row I would like to remember position of focused element before, and come back to it(like video segments on YouTube TV)  is it possible?

I am trying to use remember value but it take index of focused element in other row.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to always focus on the first item while focussing on a TVLazyRow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76880923/how-to-always-focus-on-the-first-item-while-focussing-on-a-tvlazyrow)

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem. I saw this question before, https://stackoverflow.com/users/8822610/vighnesh153, but it doesn't solve my problem unfortunately.