# How to always focus on the first item while focussing on a TVLazyRow?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I am trying to implement a TVLazyRow where when we focus on the row from some other composable above the row it must always focus on the first item first. Currently, when pressing down, the focus goes to whichever item in the row is directly below the composable above. How can I achieve this behaviour?

Here is my code for more context:

```
val tvListState = rememberTvLazyListState()
val coScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

TvLazyRow(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(15.dp),
        state = tvListState,
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .padding(end = 5.dp)
            .onFocusChanged {
                if (it.isFocused) {
                    coScope.launch {
                        tvListState.scrollToItem(0)
                    }
                }
            }, pivotOffsets = PivotOffsets(0f)
) { *items* }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Latest: November 1st, 2023

The focus restoration API is now improved and accepts a fallback focus requester which will be used when visiting a unvisited list. Because of this new change, we now don't need the modifier factory that I created earlier.

```kotlin
val firstItemToGainFocusFr = remember { FocusRequester() }

TvLazyRow(
  modifier = Modifier.focusRestorer { firstItemToGainFocusFr }
) {
  item { 
    Button(
      onClick = {}, 
      modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(firstItemToGainFocusFr)
    ) { 
      Text("My Button 1") 
    } 
  }
  item { Button(onClick = {}) { Text("My Button 2") } }
  item { Button(onClick = {}) { Text("My Button 3") } }
  // ...
}
```

---

### Edit August 11th, 2023

You can make use of the focusRestoration APIs which were released recently in the alpha version of compose foundation. Reference: [saveFocusedChild()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/focus/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusRequesterModifierNode).saveFocusedChild()) and [restoreFocusedChild()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/focus/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusRequesterModifierNode).restoreFocusedChild())

You can tap into the focusProperties and when the focus enters the container, you can check if there was a previously saved focused child. If yes, you transfer focus to that child, else, you transfer focus to the first child. While exiting the container, you can save the previously focused child.

You can create the following modifier factory which will abstract away this logic for you:

```kotlin
data class FocusRequesterModifiers(
    val parentModifier: Modifier,
    val childModifier: Modifier
)

@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun createFocusRestorationModifiers(): FocusRequesterModifiers {
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val childFocusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

    val parentModifier = Modifier
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        .focusProperties {
            exit = {
                focusRequester.saveFocusedChild()
                FocusRequester.Default
            }
            enter = {
                if (!focusRequester.restoreFocusedChild())
                    childFocusRequester
                else
                    FocusRequester.Cancel
            }
        }

    val childModifier = Modifier.focusRequester(childFocusRequester)

    return FocusRequesterModifiers(parentModifier, childModifier)
}
```

With the above factory in place, you can make use of it in your lazy containers like following:

```kotlin
val modifiers = createFocusRestorationModifiers()

TvLazyRow(
  modifier = Modifier.then(modifiers.parentModifier)
) {
  item { 
    Button(
      onClick = {}, 
      modifier = Modifier.then(modifiers.childModifier)
    ) { 
      Text("My Button 1") 
    } 
  }
  item { Button(onClick = {}) { Text("My Button 2") } }
  item { Button(onClick = {}) { Text("My Button 3") } }
  // ...
}
```

Notice, in the above example usage that we just need to assign the parent modifier to the `TvLazyRow` container and the child modifier to the first item. You can choose to assign it to the second or third item as well in case you desire that the second or third item should gain focus for the first time.

Comment: Helo is the Nov 1 update available for alpha10? or its one of the latest snapshots?

Comment: This is not part of TV libs. This is part of `androidx.compose.ui` version 1.6.0-alpha06 and above. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.6.0-alpha06. Try `beta-02`.

Comment: Hello @vighnesh153 using this approach, I noticed that rows tend to focus on the last item focussed in that row when coming back to that particular row. The usecase I want to implement is that no matter what happens, when we focus on the row, we should always focus to the first item. Any ideas how to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: For that case, you will have to create a modifier factory as I had created in the initial draft. Then, replace the `enter` block in `focusProperties` with this: `enter = { childFocusRequester }` which will always request focus on the first focus requester.

Comment: Hello @vighnesh153, another question here, can we choose which item to focus on based on some flag? The implemenentation I am trying out is if we exit out a row by pressing right from the last item, we would jump to the first item of the next row in the column and vice versa if we exit out using left from the first item, we jump to the last item of the previous row.

Comment: Can you create a new question for it? It involves a lot of different things that we need to take care of.

Comment: Hi @vighnesh153, please find the newly drafted question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/77844171/11250768