# How to focus on a specific item in a row based on some flag?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

Consider the following code :

```
val tvListState = rememberTvLazyListState()
val coScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
Column{
    TvLazyRow(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(15.dp),
        state = tvListState,
        modifier = modifier
        .padding(end = 5.dp)
        , pivotOffsets = PivotOffsets(0f)) { *items* }
    TvLazyRow(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(15.dp),
        state = tvListState,
        modifier = modifier
        .padding(end = 5.dp)
        , pivotOffsets = PivotOffsets(0f)) { *items* }
    TvLazyRow(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(15.dp),
        state = tvListState,
        modifier = modifier
        .padding(end = 5.dp)
        , pivotOffsets = PivotOffsets(0f)) { *items* }
}
```

What I want to do is to focus on a specific item in one of the lazy rows when we enter the row, and have it tied to a flag, could be something like `preFocusOnItem`. In my current implementation I am having to call focus on this item using `itemsRequester[preFocusOnItem].requestfocus()` inside `LaunchedEffect`, where the array is used to assign a focus requester to each of the items. The problem with this approach is the focus first comes to the item that scrolling naturally will bring focus to, and after a split second the focus jumps to the item I want to focus on.

How do I directly call focus on the `preFocusOnItem` item when entering one of the `TvLazyRows`??

Comment: D-Pad navigation should be straightforward and predictable. We shouldn't try to build a solution where users have to learn a new way of navigating through items on TV. Checkout [D-Pad navigation guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/ui/tv/guides/foundations/navigation-on-tv#d-pad-navigation). Nevertheless, I will try to draft a solution sometime this week which might scale for your usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `focusProperties` on the `TvLazyRow` to intercept the focus and implement the `enter` function in it to match with some condition and return respective focus requesters.

In the following example, I am focussing on:

- index 2 in first row
- index 3 in second row
- index 1 in 3rd row

[image]

```kotlin
val rows = 3
val columns = 4

val focusRequesters = remember {
    (1..(rows * columns)).map { FocusRequester() }
}

Surface(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    TvLazyColumn {
        items(rows) { row ->
            TvLazyRow(
                modifier = Modifier.focusProperties {
                    enter = {
                        when (row) {
                            0 -> focusRequesters[row * columns + 2]
                            1 -> focusRequesters[row * columns + 3]
                            2 -> focusRequesters[row * columns + 1]
                            else -> FocusRequester.Default
                        }
                    }
                }
            ) {
                items(columns) { column ->
                    val index = row * columns + column

                    AppCard(column, Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequesters[index]))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalTvMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AppCard(index: Int, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Surface(
        onClick = {},
        modifier = modifier.width(200.dp).aspectRatio(16f / 9)
    ) {
        Text(text = "Card=$index")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a downside using/saving tons of FocusRequesters? If yes, would it matter on modern android tvs nowadays?

Comment: If your screen has a lot of cards being shown lazily, then, you end up storing focus requesters for all of them in memory which might cause some out-of-memory exceptions. On top of my head, I can think of 2 ways to handle this. First, store the focus requesters in a map and dispose them if the associated item goes out of view. This way, at any point of time, you will only have focus requesters of items present in view port. Second, not use this custom focus logic and just use [focusRestorer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76881628/8822610) modifier which aligns with TV app development guidelines.

Comment: And you're right, we'll need to continue focusing on memory optimization since many people will still be using older TV models, even as hardware specifications improve.

Comment: Thanks @vighnesh153, this gives a lot more control on the focus behaviour of lazy lists

Answer (score 0):

You can set an initial scroll position to a `LazyColumn` or `LazyRow` by using the default [`rememberLazyListState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#rememberLazyListState(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int)) like this:

```
// this will initialize scrolling position to the 5th item in the LazyList
val listState = rememberLazyListState(initialFirstVisibleItemIndex = 5)

LazyRow(
    state = listState
) {
    // ...
}
```